# Spring Boot trying to create mongo repositories in tests using @JsonTest annotations

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, junit

I have an application using SpringBoot2 with mongodb and I am trying to test json serialization of some DTOS by making tests like:

```
@JsonTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class SomeDTOTest {
    @Autowired
    JacksonTester < SomeDTO > json;

    @Test
    public void someTest() {}
}
```

However underneath spring is trying to create repository bean and giving me informations:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

A component required a bean named 'mongoTemplate' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'mongoTemplate' in your configuration.
```

I have more integration test that is using the repository and are annotated with @SpringBootTests and they are working fine...

Is there a way of restricting spring to only creating JacksonTester bean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just create a test without spring runner.

This is an example [example test](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/json/JacksonTester.html)

When loading the spring context if there is an autowired annotation of a mongotemplate somewhere spring will try to provide it. You might consider:

1. Provided mongo template in tests

   Try using *@DataMongoTest* which will provide an embedded database.
2. Set an Autowired not required

   Use *@Autowired(required= false)*
3. Mock mongotemplate

   Use *@MockBean* annotation in order to mock mongoTemplate

Answer (score 1):

I found it quite challenging to have both Integration tests as well as Unit tests in a Spring Boot application. 
I checked Spring website and tried many solutions. The one that worked for me was to exclude the AutoConfiguration classes:

```
 @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
 @JsonTest(excludeAutoConfiguration = EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class)
 public class JsonTests {

      @Autowired
      private JacksonTester json;

      @MockBean
      private MyRepository repository;

      @MockBean
      private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

      @Test
      public void someTest() {}
 }
```

You can find a complete Spring Boot application that include Integration and Unit tests [here](https://github.com/a-hosseini/Automobile-Maintenance-Tracker).